# Show that the integers 1111, 111111, 11111111, ... (numbers formed by an even number of numbers 1) are all composed.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, repunit-numbers

I am studying congruence and I am trying to solve this problem, but I cannot think of a way to do this.

Would anyone be able to help me?

Show that the integers 1111, 111111, 11111111, ... (numbers formed by an even number of numbers 1) are all composed.

Comment: The one such number that you didn't include is a big hint.

Comment: Hint:Divisibility by 11

Comment: Your numbers can be written as $$11\cdots1 = \frac{99\cdots 9}{9} = \frac{10^{2n}-1}9.$$

Now can you think of a number $m$ relatively prime to $9$ such that $10^{2n}-1 \equiv 0 \pmod m$?

Comment: I think by "composed" in the title you meant *composite*.

Comment: and "composed" in the body

Comment: 11 is composite?

Comment: @hardmath You're right, I don't goofed. Sorry, Tanner.

Comment: @Arthur:  I rolled back Lieutenant Zipp's edit because it introduced the error noted by yourself and fellow Commenter Mars...

Comment: Why roll back my edit? Why not just re-edit it to remove the offending 11 from the problem statement? Now it's relatively worse-formed and worse-formatted.